# Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_{n}$, where $G$ is set of matrices of the form $\pmatrix{ \pm1 & k \\ 0 & 1}$  and all the entries are in $\mathbb Z_{n}$ for $n\ge2$.

I have already proved that $G$ is a group under multiplication.

I think I would have to use the definition of isomorphism and find a bijective map. However, I am unsure how I would do that.
Is there a theorem that I am missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to experiment, say with $n =2$?  Find the elements of each of the finite groups. Please do so if not, and report back.

Comment: $D_n$ is generated by a rotation (of order $n$) and a symmetry (of order $2$). Can you identify the corresponding matrices?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group

Comment: @user26857 But how would you show that there exists an isomorphism between one of the matrices of $D_{n}$ and $G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check $\pmatrix{ -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$ is $\sigma$ with order 2,
$\pmatrix{ 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}$ is rotation $\tau$ with order n.